# Java - Calling a public method (not public void)

Tags: java, class, methods

I have this code but I am unsure how to call the public `create()` method with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method in a different class. I have searched the net but found nothing on just public methods just public void methods.

Here is the code

mainclass.java:

```
public class Mainclass {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    create createObject = new create();
    createObject.create();
    System.out.println("dammit");

    }

}
```

create.java

```
public class Create extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public create() {
            initComponents();
            setDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Class name always starts with Upper Case Letter [check](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is actually a constructor. You call it with `new`.

```
 create panel = new create();
```

Having a class with a lowercase name is highly unorthodox.

Comment: Thank you heaps!!! As you can see I'm quite new to java. I will accept your answer when it lets me in 10 min :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

That is a constructor, not a normal method. You can see that it has the same name as the class it's in. It's called here:

```
create createObject = new create();
```

BTW, calling a class `create` makes me a sad panda.

Answer (score 2):

```
public create() {
            initComponents();
            setDate();
    }
```

`create()` Is a constructor so when you say `Create createObject = new Create();` the without parametrized constructor will automatically call.

read here for [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

and please follow the java naming conventions class name always start with caps letter.

Answer (score 1):

*Starting with something Off-topic but* you might want to read about the [Java Naming Convention](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html) to understand how to name your classes/methods/variables in Java.

Constructors as we know have declarations that look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type. So you can have something like this:

```
public class create extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    /** Normal Constructor */
    public create() {
    }

    /**
    * Normal method for initialization.
    */
    public void create(){
        initComponents();
        setDate();
    }
}
```

I tend to prefer having a specific method to handle object initialization (*or setup, if you may*) for my classes i.e. kept all business logic separate from object creation mechanism. So, if I were you, I would've renamed my method as `public void doCreate()` and initialized everything over there. (*This is subjective and a matter of preference*). With this case, my `MainClass` would have changed something like this:

```
public class MainClass {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        create createObject = new create();
        createObject.doCreate();
        System.out.println("dammit");
    }
}
```